# IE7 parent div auto-applying clear:both to div closing tag

Tags: css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

given the following code:

```
<!doctype html>
<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid red;width:500px;overflow:visible;">
<div style="height:200px;border:1px solid orange;float:right;">test</div>
</div>
stuff
```

Every browser other than IE7 (and IE8 in IE7 compatibility) displays this properly, however in IE7 the parent div automatically expands to the height of the floated child.

Is there any way to disable this "feature" so that I can have a floated div go beyond the parent's closing tag?

Answer (score 1):

You have to prevent your outer `div` from obtaining [`hasLayout`](http://www.satzansatz.de/cssd/onhavinglayout.html).

Certain things force `hasLayout`, and `width: <anything other than "auto">` is one of them.

*(Your original code for comparison: http://jsfiddle.net/T6QsS/)*

For instance, removing the `width` works in IE7: http://jsfiddle.net/T6QsS/1/

To use `width`, you must add it to an extra wrapper element: http://jsfiddle.net/T6QsS/2/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, however because of the way the project is set up the div must contain the width (as it is the wrapper) and must close directly after the float, is there any way using htc or anything to disable this portion of IE7?

Comment: Sure, you can use JavaScript to work around it (which is what a `.htc` file uses). @Briguy37's answer might work for you, see if that works for you before turning to JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

One option is if you know the desired height of the parent, you can specify it in the parent div.  For example, in your case:

```
<!doctype html>
<div style="position:relative;border:1px solid red;width:500px;overflow:visible; height: 0px;">
<div style="height:200px;border:1px solid orange;float:right;">test</div>
</div>
stuff
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/briguy37/6JUaK/)'s a fiddle to test.

Answer (score 0):

You could target IE7 using the `*` CSS hack. Try this:
http://jsbin.com/ufoqo5/2/edit

Comment: Thanks, this seems to work as long as I add a few extra wrappers so valid content in the wrapper gets displayed (then put a new wrapper around the *height:0 portion).